# Some rating options have been disabled based on the content of your application

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-games, rating

I have an error in my developer console:

> "Some rating options have been disabled based on the content of your application"

near the content rating section of my application and I'm left with only Medium or High Maturity. I think it appeared after recent update which was adding **Google Play Games Services** to my game. I don't have any permissions in my **Android Manifest** which can be a reason for that only INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. I also use **Google AdMob** but I'm filtering most of the sensitive-category-ads so that it can't be a reason. Also content of the game itself perfectly suits Everyone category. I have asked Google support team but they didn't help me much, at best sending me to their content rating guidelines.

That being said is there any other reason which can create that kind of problem or maybe I'm missing something?

Worth mentioning that my game is in Beta and got only few downloads by my friends.

Comment: "but I'm filtering **most** of the sensitive-category-ads so that it can't be a reason" - maybe you have to filter them all?

Comment: Maybe that's the case but on another hand I've read in similar questions that even if you don't filter any of them you should still be able to select Low Maturity.